# Robots.txt file and Googlebot crawability

Tags: web-crawler, robots.txt

Will this `robots.txt` allow Googlebot to crawl my site or not?

```
Disallow: /
User-agent: Robozilla
Disallow: /
User-agent: *
Disallow:
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Sitemap: https://koyal.pk/sitemap/sitemap.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how Google will react to a robots.txt file, you should get an official answer by testing in [Google's robots.txt testing tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en).  Here I have the results of such a test using the robots.txt that you provided:

[image]

Googlebot will be able to crawl the site, however Google tells you that the robots.txt syntax you are using as a problem. I see several problems:

- A `Disallow` directive *must* have a `User-agent` directive somewhere above it.
- There should be a new line before each `User-agent` directive (except the one at the beginning of the file.)
- The `Disallow:` line means "allow all crawling".  That should only be used if there are no other `Disallow` rules.

A syntactically correct robots.txt that I think would do what you intend is:

```
User-agent: Robozilla
Disallow: /

User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Sitemap: https://koyal.pk/sitemap/sitemap.xml
```

That would provent the `Robozilla` bot from crawling while allowing all other bots (including Googlebot) to crawl everything except the `/cgi-bin/` directory.